# Php with mysql won't connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've tried every way to connect MySQL with PHP and it doesn't work. I think there may be a issue with phpMyAdmin and MySQL terminal because when I make a table in the terminal it doesn't show up in phpMyAdmin. Is that unusual?

Also when I click on Server: localhost in phpMyAdmin a 404 error message comes up, Is that normal?

I used this code which puts a 0 in my browser which means it should be working. If I change my credentials it will echo 1045. So it should be working.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'db_demo');
echo $db->connect_errno;
```

Comment: Sounds like your stack isn't configured properly. It is an OOB install (such as XAMPP, WAMP or somesuch), or did you buidl it yourself?

Comment: What errors are being outputted on your page?

Comment: belongs to Superuser?

Comment: It's on MAMP, and Yeah I think it might be something under the hood. @BenM

Comment: check if mysql is running or not..

Comment: @Enijar If I change my credentials it will output 1045. But like is it puts out 0.

Comment: @Vamsi MySQL is running.

Answer (score 0):

404 means your request not found in the server. Make sure whether your phpmyadmin located in the right directory.
If everything is OK you should configure phpmyadmin, please find file named "config.inc.php" to setup your host, mysql username, mysql password, etc.

Comment: Any idea where phpmyadmin would be located? On a mac using MAMP.

Comment: Try to go to http://localhost:8888/MAMP and you will see a page. Click phpmyadmin on that page.

Comment: Link didn't work... It's weird because my localhost has that error but it's allowing me to post info from phpMyAdmin to my server. So, I don't know.

Comment: "Allowing me to post info from phpmyadmin to my server". Sorry i didn't get it, what do you mean? :)

Comment: I don't even know man... I'm deleting it all and re-downloading everything with XAMPP. I've been trying to figure this out for to long. Thanks for your inout.